# Convert rupee to paise

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert rupee to paise. 1 rupee is 100 paise.

`paise =  parseFloat("4532.6523").toFixed(2)*100 //453264.99999999994`

How do I get only 453265 only

Comment: `Math.round` to round to nearest integer

Comment: paise = (parseFloat("4532.6523")*100).toFixed(2)

Comment: `paise = Math.floor(parseFloat("4532.6523") * 100)`